# Showing equivalence of general position and linear independence - Armstrong

Tags: linear-algebra, algebraic-topology

Let $v_0, v_1, \ldots, v_k$ be points of euclidean n-space $\mathbb{R}^n$. The hyperplane spanned by these points consists of all linear combinations $\lambda_0 v_0 + \ldots
+ \lambda_k v_k$ where each $\lambda_i$ is a real number and the sum of the $\lambda_i$ is 1. The points are in general position if any subset of them spans a strictly smaller hyperplane. If we regard $\mathbb{R}^n$ as a vector space, this is equivalent to asking that the vectors $v_1 - v_0, v_2 - v_0, \ldots , v_k - v_0$ be linearly independent.

I'm unsure how to show this last part. I can't find a way to show that the linear independence implies the general position.

Comment: Hint: Try writing $\lambda_0v_0+\dotsc+\lambda_kv_k$ with coefficients summing to $1$ as an arbitrary linear combination of the $v_1-v_0,\dotsc,v_k-v_0$.

Comment: I have that $\lambda_0 v_0 + \ldots + \lambda_k v_k = 
\lambda_k (v_k - v_0) + \ldots + \lambda_1 (v_1 - v_0) + v_0$, but I'm not sure how to conclude that no subset thus spans a strictly smaller hyperplane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $M = \lbrace v_0,\ldots, v_k \rbrace$ and $M_0 = \lbrace v_1-v_0,\ldots, v_k-v_0 \}$. We write $H(M)$ for the hyperplane spanned by $M$ and $W(M_0)$ for the linear subspace of $\mathbb R^n$ spanned by $M_0$. We claim
$$H(M) = v_0 + W(M_0) = \lbrace v_0+w \mid w \in W(M_0)  \rbrace .$$

1. Let $x \in v_i + W(M_0)$. Then $x = v_0 + \sum_{i=1}^k\mu_i(v_i-v_0) = (1 - \sum_{i=1}^k\mu_i)v_0 + \sum_{i=1}^k\mu_iv_i$. Since $1 - \sum_{i=1}^k\mu_i + \sum_{i=1}^k\mu_i = 1 $, we see that $x \in H(M)$.
2. Let $x \in H(M)$. Then $x = \sum_{i=0}^k\lambda_iv_i$ with $\sum_{i=0}^k\lambda_i = 1$. Therefore $x = v_0 + \sum_{i=0}^k\lambda_iv_i -v_0 = v_0 + \sum_{i=0}^k\lambda_iv_i - \sum_{i=0}^k\lambda_iv_0 = v_0 +  \sum_{i=0}^k\lambda_i(v_i -v_0) =$ $ v_0 +  \sum_{i=1}^k\lambda_i(v_i -v_0) \in v_0 + W(M_0)$.

Now let $v_1-v_0,\ldots, v_k-v_0$ be linearly dependent. Then some $v_i-v_0$ is a linear combination of the other $v_j - v_0$. Let $M' = \lbrace v_0, \ldots, \hat v_i, \ldots, v_k \rbrace$. Here $\hat v_i$ means that the $i$-th element in the sequence $v_0, \ldots,  v_k$ is omitted. Similarly let $M_0' = \lbrace v_1-v_0, \ldots, \widehat {v_i -v_0}, \ldots, v_k-v_0 \rbrace$. Clearly $M'_0$ spans $W(M_0)$. Therefore
$$H(M') = v_0 + W(M'_0) = v_0 + W(M_0) = H(M)$$
which shows that the points in $M$ are not in general position.

Next let $v_1-v_0,\ldots, v_k-v_0$ be linearly independent. To show that any proper subset of $M$ spans a strictly smaller hyperplane, it suffices to consider a subset of the form $M' = \lbrace v_0, \ldots, \hat v_i, \ldots, v_k \rbrace$.

Case 1. $i > 0$. Then $H(M') = v_0 + W(M'_0)$. Since $v_i - v_0 \notin M'_0$, we see that $W(M'_0)$ is strictly smaller than $W(M_0)$ which finishes the proof.

Case 2. $i = 0$. Then $M' = \lbrace v_1, \ldots, v_k\rbrace$. With $M'_1 = \lbrace v_2-v_1, \ldots v_k-v_1 \rbrace$ we get
$H(M') = v_1 + W(M'_1)$. We claim that $v_0 \notin H(M')$ which shows that  $H(M')$ strictly smaller than $H(M)$. So let us assume $v_0 \in H(M'_1)$. Then $v_0 = v_1 + w$ with $w = \sum_{i=2}^k \mu_i (v_i-v_1)$. Thus $v_1 - v_0 + \sum_{i=2}^k\mu_i (v_i-v_1) = 0$. Since $v_1-v_0 \ne 0$  (recall the linear independence assumption), we conclude that not all $\mu_i = 0$. We get
$$0 = v_1 - v_0 + \sum_{i=2}^k\mu_i (v_i-v_1) = v_1 - v_0 + \sum_{i=2}^k\mu_i (v_i-v_0 + v_0 - v_1)\\ = (1 - \sum_{i=2}^k\mu_i)(v_1-v_0) + \sum_{i=2}^k\mu_i (v_i-v_0) $$
which contradicts the linear independence assumption.